# Sort null/empty date properties last, regardless of ASC or DESC

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I have a data table on my page that allows the user to sort a column by clicking its header. Click it once, ASC, click it twice, DESC.

However, one of the Date fields that I'm sorting by has a few null values (no dates have been inputted for that particular submission yet).

I can get it to sort "properly", where ASC lists the row with the empty Date fields first, and DESC lists them last, but I need the the rows with empty date fields to *always* appear last, regardless of whether the column is sorted ASC or DESC.

The problem is, once I sort everything 'correctly', sorting by ASC correctly places all the null LatestSubmission values at the bottom. However, when I toggle the DESC, those null LatestSubmission values naturally go to the top. I'm trying to figure out how to get those rows with empty LatestSubmission values at the bottom *regardless of whether it is sorted ASC or DESC*.

I've been messing around with the `sortDirection` boolean, so that may make things more confusing; it's certainly redundant. However, I'm pretty lost at this point and any change I seem to make just breaks it even more, heh.

Here is what I believe to be the relevant code, but I am new so please let me know if more is required.

All that comes before is a switch statement that determines which column was clicked and thus which to sort. `LatestSubmission` also happens to be the default case.

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
rows.sort((a, b) =>
{
    /* A bunch of cases that don't matter for this problem */
    case "LatestSubmission":
    default:
        defaultCase = true;
        return (this.#sort_LatestSubmission(pitchA.LatestSubmission, pitchB.LatestSubmission, sortDirection)) * sortDirection;

    #sort_LatestSubmission = (a_LatestSubmission, b_LatestSubmission, sortDirection) =>
    {
        return ((!(b_LatestSubmission?.DateSubmitted)) - (!(a_LatestSubmission?.DateSubmitted))) * 
         !sortDirection || (a_LatestSubmission?.DateSubmitted - b_LatestSubmission?.DateSubmitted);
    }
```

Thank you for reading.